# Selenium. Selenide. Class file for org.openqa.selenium.WrapsDriver not found for some reason

Tags: java, maven, selenium, automated-tests, selenide

I am using Java in Maven project. When I try to use Selenide functions in my tests I am getting this error:

`Error:(39, 26) java: cannot access org.openqa.selenium.WrapsDriver
  class file for org.openqa.selenium.WrapsDriver not found`

At the same time my tests works good without Selenide code.

Here is my POM xml:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
        <version>3.13.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.12</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.codeborne</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenide</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.codeborne</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenide</artifactId>
        <version>RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Comment: are you testing the web or mobile app?

Comment: I am testing web

Answer (score 9):

the problem was solved by adding depandancy

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.14.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

To explain the answer in detail:
When we add the dependency selenium-java, it pulls under the hood among others selenium api dependency:

```
    org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-java -> 3.141.59
    +--- org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-api:3.141.59
    +--- org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-chrome-driver:3.141.59  
         +--- org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-api:3.141.59
```

Now if you have any other dependency which also pulls the selenium-api as a transitive dependency(in this case I think that is selenide) then there will be a version mismatch which causes error.

By explicitly declaring the dependency as

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
    <artifactId>selenium-api</artifactId>
    <version>3.14.0</version>
</dependency>
```

We tell our build management tool (which can also be gradle besides maven) which exact version of selenium api to pull and hence problem is solved.